# Coding standards: Should one always write 'return' at the end of every method or function?

Tags: python, code-standards

I believe that the question is **not a duplicate** as the other question does not respond to the question of readability.

In the contributing guidelines of the library `scikit-learn`, they refer to a document for coding standards, see [here](https://gist.github.com/nateGeorge/5455d2c57fb33c1ae04706f2dc4fee01), in which you can find the following remarks:

```
        # Functions/methods that do not return a value should still be
        # delimited by a return statement.  Please tell me you don't have to
        # ask why!
        return
```

However, there is no difference in the return value, and I don't see the improvements in readability of the code. I looked for people that detailed this point, but none of them tackled this subject from the angle of readability.

So why is it better to write `return` everytime ?

Comment: As someone who started by learning c and c++ code, and isn't super familiar with python yet, seeing the return gives me a sense of security, but I don't think that would be a problem with anyone with a bit more experience.

Comment: "Please tell me you don't have to ask why!" This kind of language makes my blood boil.

Comment: That documentation's a little condescending, eh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example they refer to the return statement as a delimiter, hence a visual way to identify the end of a function block.

This is not an official part of PEP and personally I don't think it is necessary as Python has strong enough visual cues with indentation.